# Has hypnopaedia been proven to work? To what extent?

Tags: sleep, memory, learning

The idea of learning during sleep, say by listening to a recorded class, can be tempting to make a good use of roughly a third of the day. Has it ever worked though? If so what is the most efficient method to retain information?

Comment: It seems like it has worked, but usually only when you're in the stage where alpha activity occurs, which is just before you wake up. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep-learning

Comment: The fact that most research is circa 1960 and that hypnopaedia is promoted mostly in self-growth/self-help sites suggests that there isn't strong scientific support on the concept.